# What does the expectation value of $x$ mean? Surely it must expectation value of a function of $x$?

Tags: statistics, expectation

How can a value of $x$ have an expectation value? Surely there must be a distribution of values of $x$ for the expectation value to be calculated. Is this the reason for the normal distribution function? When finding the mean of the normal distribution function do you have to do: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xN(x)dx$$ Where $N(x)$ is the normal distribution funtion.

Or should it be: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty N(x)p(x)dx$$ Where $p(x)$ is some probability density function.

Also, am I right in thinking that the expectation value is essentially the mean?

Comment: FYI the integrals and in general when applying "_" in latex use "blah_{blah 2}" as the method for keeping all of "blah 2" subscript..also works for superscript.

Comment: When you say "a value of $x$", what's $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The first integral is correct since you are computing 
$$
E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdP = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx 
$$
where $dP$ is the probability measure, and $f(x)$ is the probability density function (in your case the Normal).
The above also evaluates to the mean.

To answer another question..the value of $x$ is better described as
$$
E(X) = \int_{x\in A} xf(x)dx 
$$
where the set of values of $x$ are only considered if they exist in $A$

$$
E(g(X)) = \int_{x\in A} g(x)f(x)dx
$$
I am not caring about the subtle/or not subtle cases of existence of the integral..but if we take
$$
g(X) = X^2
$$
we can compute
$$
E(g(X)) = E(X^2) = \int_{x\in A} x^2f(x)dx
$$

Comment: How is an expectation value of a function calculated? Is this ever done?

Comment: yes .. and a great question. I will update.

Comment: @user3764899 The expectation value is something that you calculate for a random variable. You can also apply a function to a random variable, but the result is still a random variable and you calculate the expected value of that.

Comment: @user3764899 it depends on what $p(x)$ is..There was comment that was deleted, which basically made a correct statement that the measure does not have to exist over for the given support that I have stated in the first line. But for the normal distribution it will be ok to use $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)N(x)dx$$ (but this is subject to far better mathematicians than myself ;) )